# Using "or" to find if any of a string is in a row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, boolean, boolean-logic, opencsv

example file (.csv): in row[0] there is "d e f b c c c a"

```
file=open("example_file.csv","r")

column=""

for row in file:
    if "a" or "b" or "c" in row[0]:
        column+=row
```

I'm trying to figure out a way that if the file has a,b or c in the row it will print only the a's b's or c's

Comment: Look up the `any(...)` function.

Comment: The question this is a duplicate of uses `==`, but the `in` operator works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**any function**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if (any(x in row[0] for x in ("a", "b", "c"))):
    column += row
```

Comment: Or `any(x in row[0] for x in 'abc')`

Comment: @alec: I guess, `a`, `b` and `c` are only placeholders so iterating over a string does not make much sense.

Comment: I ended up using 3 if statements for "a" "b" and "c" separately. It was kinda time sensitive but thanks for all the answers. Im going to update my code with them